# Why this xpath fails

Tags: xslt, xpath, windward

I have the following xml file

```
<applications>
   <application>
      <forms>
          <questions>
              <first_name>
                   My Name
              </first_name>
          </questions>
      </forms>
    </application>
</applications>
```

First I have a for each loop which runs through all applications and assigns a variable app to a current application. Then I test each application like this:

```
<wr:if select="${app}/forms/questions/first_name" notEmpty="true">Print this if succeeded</wr:if>
```

I am trying to test if there is a text in first_name tag, but in the end I always have empty string, I guess my if does not succeed. Do you know if I made a mistake in my xpath?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use text():

```
<wr:if select="${app}/forms/questions/first_name/text()" notEmpty="true">Print this if succeeded</wr:if>
```